# Convertir Array a string para insertarlo en mi base de datos

Tags: php, angular

Necesito convertir mi Array en un string antes de insertarlo en mi base de datos MySQL, al intentar insertar el array me dice el siguiente error

**Type:** ErrorException

**Code:** 8

**Message:** Array to string conversion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El array me lo guarda con "comas" es un multiselect debajo del multiselect se puede ver como lo está guardando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la funcion **implode()**, que te convierte un array en un string con los elementos del array separados por el delimitador que tu quieras.

```
$string_programa = implode(',',$data['programa]);
//Después almacenas $string_programa en la DB
```

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php

El caso al revés es la función **explode()** que te convierte un string separado por un delimitador, en un array.

Comment: Hola @JuanLuis muchas gracias por tu respuesta, añado esto encima de mi query $string_programa = implode(',',$data['programa']); y en el insert into pongo "'{$data['$string_programa']}'," . ??

Comment: No, en el insert mete $string_programa. Echale un vistazo a los arrays asociativos en php y a funciones con arrays. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría realizar un `var_dump` de `$data` para que sepas cada elemento que guardas de que tipo es y cual te puede estar dando problemas o cual debes convertirlo.

¿Puedes mostrar la salida que te da `var_dump($data)`?

Puedes utilizar la función `strval()` para realizar la conversión de tipos de una variable.