# Como convertir un array en un string en laravel?

Tags: laravel, array, string

Muy buenas tardes quiera obtener su ayuda para resolver un problema que tengo no encuentro la forma de convertir el array obtenido de un select multiple para poder guardarlo en mi base de datos les comparto mi codigo.

```html
public function store(Request $Request)
    {

        $data = new Perm;

        if($data->validate($Request->all(),'add'))
        {
            return redirect::back()->withErrors($data->validate($Request->all(),'add'))->withInput();
            exit;
        }

        $data->addNew($Request->all(),"add");

        return redirect(env('admin').'/adminUser')->with('message','New Record Added Successfully.');
    }
```

Ese es el codigo de mi controlado el cual obtengo los datos del formulario y mando a llamar la funcion addNew de mi modelo

```html
public function addNew($data,$type)
    {
        $add                  = $type === 'add' ? new Perm : Perm::find($type);
        $add->name            = isset($data['name']) ? $data['name'] : null;
        $add->username          = isset($data['username']) ? $data['username'] : null;

         $array = $data['perm'];
            dd($array);
         foreach($array as $valor){


         }

       // $add->perm               = isset($data['perm']) ? $data['perm'] : 0;

        if(isset($data['password']))
        {
            $add->password  = bcrypt($data['password']);
            $add->shw_password = $data['password'];
        }

        $add->save();
    }
```

El array que obtengo es este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dada por este codigo en el view

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="inputEmail6">Assign Permission</label>
<select name="perm[]" class="form-control js-select2" multiple="true">
@foreach(DB::table('perm')->get() as $p)
<option value="{{ $p->perm }}" @if(in_array($p->perm,$array)) selected @endif>{{ $p->perm }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No entiendo... ¿cuál es el array? Por el título me parece que lo que preguntas es lo mismo que aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/275045/convertir-array-a-string-para-insertarlo-en-mi-base-de-datos

Comment: ya modifique esos puntos que pides.

Comment: No entiendo, la idea es almacenar completo el array en una celda o descomponerlo en múltiples renglones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para guardar un `array` en tu base de datos, necesitas convertir ese `array` en un `JSON`. Para eso usamos la función de `json_encode()`, de la siguiente manera:

```
$array = ['element1', 'element2'];
$json = json_encode($array);

$object_model->data= $json; // Por ejemplo un $user->data, donde data es una columna de la tabla users, la columna data debe de ser de tipo longText() o string si no esperas un array grande

$object_model->save();
```

De esa manera, es como almacenas la información de un `array` en tu base de datos.

Comment: de tal manera que json_encode me convertiría el array en string y me lo guardaría en una columna? `$add->perm = json_encode($data['perm'];` esa seria la forma?

Comment: Es correcto, lo que hace esa función, convierte el array en un json que, a fin de cuentas, es una cadena de caracteres. Y listo

Comment: @ANTONYREBOLLEDOMATUS si mi respuesta te sirvió, te pido que la marques como correcta y votes arriba, gracias